# How to split the string numbers and characters in asp.net

Tags: sql-server-2008, c#-4.0, asp.net-4.0

I am getting id like this(max id in Storedprocedure) "100254A"(it is string),
now i can split the string "100254" and "A" after generate the next string like 100254B.
how to write the code **generate the next strings like 100254C,...100254Z after 100255A** will coming pls give me any suggestion

Thank u
hemanth

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this can help:

```
DECLARE @String VARCHAR(200)
SET @String = '100254E'

DECLARE @number INT,
        @letter VARCHAR(5)

SET @number = CAST(LEFT(@String, LEN(@String) - 1) AS INT)
SET @letter= SUBSTRING(@String,LEN(@String), LEN(@String))
--Check if it is Z
IF(ASCII(@letter)=90)
BEGIN
    SET @number=@number+1
    SET @letter=CHAR(65)
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    SET @letter=CHAR(ASCII(@letter)+1)
END

SELECT CAST(@number AS VARCHAR(100))+@letter AS new
SELECT @String AS old
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [substring](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187748.aspx) function.

Answer (score 0):

try this hope it will help You

```
  declare @temvalue varchar(50)
  declare @givenvalue varchar(50)

  set @givenvalue ='100254A' 

 set @temvalue=  substring(@givenvalue,len(@givenvalue),1)
 set @givenvalue=substring(@givenvalue,0,len(@givenvalue))

 declare @tableid int 

 while ASCII(@temvalue)<=90
 begin
    set  @tableid=ASCII(@temvalue)
    declare  @data varchar(1)
           set @data=CHAR(@tableid)
           print @givenvalue+@data
    if @givenvalue <>'100257' -- UP TO THIS IT WILL generate  STRING
        begin
          if @tableid=90
           begin
           set @givenvalue= CAST(cast(@givenvalue as int)+1 as varchar(50))
           set @tableid=64

          end
       end
    set  @tableid+=1
    set @temvalue=CHAR(@tableid)
  end
```